# How to replace for-loop by comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have `state_array` function. If `if` state ist true, i'm deleting item from list `result`. It's not working because `for-loop` ist out of range.
I wat to fix it, and want to ask, it is possible to have list comprehension instead of 'for-loop', if yes, how to do that ?

```
def state_array(self):
    for k in range(len(result)):
        if '[0]' in str(result[k]):
            if '[7]' in str(result[k+7]) and '[8]' not in str(result[k+8]):
                result[k][0] = str(result[k][0]).replace('[0]', '').replace('X0', 'X0,8')                      # state array
                del result[k+1:k+7]
            else:
                continue
```

My input:

```
V;3;M_BB01_03[0];SPPP.BK1800.58,X0;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[1];SPPP.BK1800.58,X1;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[2];SPPP.BK1800.58,X2;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[3];SPPP.BK1800.58,X3;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[4];SPPP.BK1800.58,X4;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[5];SPPP.BK1800.58,X5;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[6];SPPP.BK1800.58,X6;RW
V;3;M_BB01_03[7];SPPP.BK1800.58,X7;RW
```

And expected output:

```
V;3;M_BB01_03[0];SPPP.BK1800.58,X0,8;RW
```

Comment: Can you give some input and expected output? If you give a code snippet that can be run completely on its own, it's a lot easier for people to help you

Comment: Duplicate of [remove items from a list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: I updated question on input and output

Comment: Is your input a list of strings?

Comment: Why do you check the 9th element when your input string has only 8 elements?

Comment: Yes, my input ist list of strings.

I'm checking the 9th element, because i what to do this function only for 8 bits array.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have too much logic in this block in order to do a clean list comprehension. I do not say it is impossible to pack it all in a list comprehension, i say it would be badly ugly. To prevent your out of range error, just replace range(len(result)) by enumerate(result).

```
def state_array(self):
for k, r in enumerate(result):
    if k+7 >= len(result):
        break
    if '[0]' in str(r):
        if '[7]' in str(result[k+7]) and '[8]' not in str(result[k+8]):
            r[0] = str(r[0]).replace('[0]', '').replace('X0', 'X0,8')                      # state array
            del result[k+1:k+7]
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: It does resolve it because instead of iterating over a fixed sized range created prior to the loop, you are iterating over the actual items. The only thing i forgot is to check if k+7 is inferior to the length of results.

Comment: So, if you use `enumerate` which yields an iterator, you don't get an IndexError if the size of the iterable changes! I didn't know that - thanks.

Comment: It's not working, i have an error: `if int(k+7) >= len(result):
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

Comment: my bad, it's k, r in enumerate(result)

Answer (score 1):

You loop from 0 to the *original* length of the array, but then you change the actual length within the loop. A quickfix to this is to use a while loop:

```
k=0
while(k<len(A)):
    if(condition)
         del(A[k])
    k=k+1
```